Is outer space Radioactive?
We are still receiving cosmic microwave background from the "big bang", and I'm pretty sure that cosmic rays produce gamma rays as mentioned here https://science.nasa.gov/ems/12_gammarays/.
So there is radioactivity in space of the order, 50-2000 mSv nasa.gov, which is a lethal amount.
As mentioned in Space Stackexchange for a similar question, it was mentioned that space suits provide limited protection against the radiation, but considering that astronauts make space walks during minimum radiation, still possesses a greater risk of radiation poisoning.
However, according to the Space Law, all satellites are supposed to fall back to Earth after 25 years of service. There is a hundred percent chance that these are radioactive prior to falling back to Earth, assuming that during the re entry to earth, not all of the equipment are destroyed, and they fall in sea, wont that cause a major risk to us humans and those traveling in cruises to catch radiation poisoning?
Additionally does integrating a boron layer inside the space suit help the astronauts from the similar radiation poisoning? As boron was used in the nuclear tragedy of 1986 Chernobyl, to cover the exploded part of the reactor to minimize the radiation?

Why do you mention the cosmic microwave background? It has nothing to do with radioactivity. It's just light that was emitted ~378,000 years after the Big Bang. It was originally visible (peaking in the orange part of the spectrum), but its wavelength has been stretched due to the expansion of space, reducing the energy of those photons.

The word you are looking for is radiation, more precisely cosmic radiation. See: https://www.cdc.gov/radiation-health/data-research/facts-stats/cosmic-radiation.html

More here: https://www.iaea.org/newscenter/news/cosmic-radiation-why-we-should-not-be-worried

No. 'Outer space' is basically nothing. Isn't that why it's called 'space'?
Outer space is full of various types of radiation but that makes it a victim, not the perpetrator you seem to be describing.
That which is radioactive first needs to be a substance, which space isn't.
That which is radioactive further needs not to receive but to emit, which space doesn't.

@RobbieGoodwin the "outer" in "outer space" seems redundant. Space is space. If it was "outer solar system", then it would have been a different matter :)

@NilayGhosh Thanks and why address that to me? FYI, some (Search it) suggest 'outer space' starts around 100km from Earth.
I have no idea whether those guys would stick to 100km on any other planet.
My own, rather loose, definition would be that distance at which purely planetary activity - such as thunderstorms - couldn't have any effect.
Others might, I guess, suggest 'outer space' began at a radius beyond which the planet's gravity ceased to ensure that most unpowered objects would be captured but to me that's too obviously thwarted by the objects' velocity.
More…

Further… 100km, or 10 or 1,000, isn't one definition specifically, the radius at which the atmosphere becomes so thin, it ceases to thwart whatever radiation we're talking about? Horses for courses, unless an internationally recognised space agency has a clear definition.
Still, why did you address that Comment to me, please?

Can we all simply recognise that while while outer space is full of radiation, which sometimes spreads down even into inner space, that can't affect the Question here?
Space cannot be radioactive because it's… uh… space.
Radioactivity can come only from objects, in space or on any astral body including planets, comets, asteroids or their like… never from the nothingness that is space.
Who could doubt that?

I think it would be useful to discuss terms before moving on. Words around radioactivity and nuclear stuff tend to get thrown around wildly in media, and it has led to some confusion about what the words actually mean.
Radioactive: A substance is radioactive if it has a tendency to spontaneously undergo an atomic change that releases energy. Space is not radioactive -- or more specifically, particles in space are generally not radioactive, and even if they were, they're not the problem.
Radiation: Radiation is just energy being emitted as fast-moving particles or photons. This is one of those 'confusion words' between scientists and the public, because all frequencies in the EM spectrum -- radio, microwaves, infrared, visible light, gamma rays, and more -- are radiation, but what most people mean is…
Ionizing Radiation: Ionizing radiation is a particle or photon that has enough energy to knock electrons off atoms that they strike*. The big three famous ones are alpha (a fast moving helium nucleus), beta (a fast electron or positron), and gamma (a high energy photon), but there's others. Free neutrons (sometimes called "neutron flux") are common in nuclear reactors, for example. The line between non-ionizing and ionizing photons is a bit fuzzy but happens in the upper ultraviolet, so anything from strong UV up through gamma or cosmic rays is ionizing. Ionizing radiation is what we mean when we talk about radiation poisoning and radiation doses. It's often a matter of context to determine if somebody (even an astronomer) who is talking about radiation means "electromagnetic energy" or "ionizing radiation".
Note that microwaves, being between radio and infrared, are not ionizing radiation. The cosmic microwave background is not dangerous in any way.
*Electron loss causes damage to living things when the ionization causes an important molecule (such as DNA) to break apart or change shape in a way that makes it nonfunctional, which leads to cell death. Mostly we recognize that as a sunburn, but what we think of as "radiation poisoning" is usually either something like a sunburn that goes all the way through the body, or damage to the sensitive linings of the gut and airways (especially when the source of the radiation was dust that has been inhaled or eaten).
Cosmic Ray Spallation
Objects that are exposed to nuclear radiation can become radioactive themselves, usually as a result of absorbing free neutrons ("neutron activation"). Free neutrons are not common in space (normally found only inside a running nuclear reactor or next to a detonating bomb), but you can get them due to cosmic ray spallation. That's when a cosmic ray hits an atom in just the right way to knock a neutron out of it and send it careening off into another atom, which can potentially make either or both of the atoms involved become unstable.
Most of the results of cosmic ray spallation are extremely short lived and break down in much less than a second. Rarely, an atom becomes long-term radioactive from the process, but overall this is happening only in very tiny amounts.
So no, satellites are not dangerously radioactive when they deorbit -- they are, technically speaking, very slightly radioactive, and that can be detected with sensitive equipment, but it's not going to poison our world or kill the people on cruise liners nearby. Don't think about a lump of plutonium or the Incredible Hulk's blood; think about uranium glass or red Fiestaware.
Anyway, cosmic rays hit the Earth all the time. If that cosmic ray hadn't hit the satellite, it would have either hit an atom in the upper atmosphere, or perhaps made it all the way down to a mountain peak and hit an atom of carbon or silicon, and we aren't concerned about that either. It's been going on for billions of years and doesn't seem to have caused any issues up to now.
Space suits
Radiation protection in space is a matter of ongoing interest. Charged particles aren't really a concern, as even your skin is plenty of defense against that sort of thing, and keeping UV off is important, but gamma and cosmic rays are the real trick here. There's no way to stop them other than sheer mass, putting enough atoms in the way to catch them, but that's exactly the opposite of what you want in a space suit (or a spacecraft, for that matter). In addition, in some cases light armor is worse than no armor. Aside from possible neutron spalling, a cosmic ray that hits a thin layer of metal foil can get converted from a single moderately dangerous ray into a shower gamma rays, each with only a fraction of the original energy but still plenty to be dangerous. There's a distinct possibility that adding a radiation protection layer to a space suit could make things worse instead of better.
We try to stay away from radiation hot zones like the Van Allen belts by picking orbits that just won't intersect them, we have the astronauts go inside if there's bad "weather" that's going to increase their dose, but ultimately, it's just an accepted risk of space travel. Airline pilots similarly accept the risk of spending most of their days high in the atmosphere where they get a higher dose of cosmic ray showers than most of us.
Since you mentioned it: Boron wouldn't help with any of this, because the purpose of boron at Chernobyl was to try to "poison" the nuclear reaction. Boron is a neutron sponge, able to easily absorb neutron flux without contributing to the ongoing chain reaction, so it's often used as an emergency scram method. Get enough of it inside a reactor core (presumably because it's going out of control), and the boron will rapidly halt the reaction so they can cool everything down in the usual ways. It probably didn't do any good at Chernobyl, but it's perhaps understandable in that situation that they'd try absolutely everything, even if it was unlikely to help.
Since an astronaut is not in the middle of an ongoing nuclear chain reaction, boron is unlikely to be useful.

There are several misconceptions in your post.

the "50-2000 mSv" figure you quote misses one essential element: the time frame. That makes that source useless.

Getting hit by a radioactive particle doesn't automatically make the hit object radioactive. That only happens when the particle hits with the right energy to knock protons or neutrons out of a nucleus, converting a stable atom into an active isotope. That is a very rare event. Only at very high levels of radiation does an exposed object become radioactive itself.


In practice, humans can live on the moon for up to 6 months before the radiation exposure becomes dangerous.
(will add more detail and sources later)

there is one scenario where an atom CAN emit radiation after being hit with high energy radiation, and that is roentgen scattering. Example from my graduation work demonstrates: when a lead target is hit with a beam of gamma photons from a Cobalt 60 source, it will emit various roentgen photons of specific energies at certain angles from the impacting gamma photons. This can be used to both steer beams or in my case for analysis of the composition of the exposed material (different materials have different emission spectra).

Space is not radioactive, but there is ionizing radiation in space. Little of that is due to radioactive material. Most of the penetrating radiation is due to particle acceleration by dynamic magnetic fields.
Exposure of matter to cosmic radiation produces little radioactivity. The main human exposure to that radioactivity is not due to artifacts returning to Earth, but from the fact that the whole Earth is exposed to cosmic radiation. In particular, cosmic rays transform atmospheric nitrogen into radioactive carbon 14, which is the source of a small part of natural background radiation.
In special circumstances, using very sensitive instrumentation, one may detect radioactivity induced in spacecraft materials by cosmic rays. The quantity is far too small to be a human health hazard.
Boron is useful for absorbing neutrons from a nuclear reactor, but there are few neutrons in space.
At the present time, there is one component of cosmic radiation whose health effects are not well understood: high energy nuclei heavier than helium. These are rare in low Earth orbit, where space stations operate, but are more common outside the magnetosphere. Current radiation protection guidelines treat their hazard as similar to helium nuclei (alpha particles), but this is more due to a lack of information than any solid science. They may be a serious hazard to long term inhabitation of space without adequate shielding mass.
